# num_rows in dba_tables not reflecting the real number of rows in tables Oracle 9i

Tags: oracle-9i

I'm querying `dba_tables` in order to get a listing of tables and their rowcount with following sql request :

```
select * from dba_tables where owner='dbSID';
```

But I notice that even for some non empty tables, `NUM_ROWS` column is returning null values.

Could somebody please explain this strange behavior of `dba_tables` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's an estimate. See http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/statviews_2105.htm#i1592091.
If you run the following :

```
exec dbms_stats.gather_schema_stats('owner');
```

within Oracle SQL*Plus. You'll get then the exact value of row numbers (until subsequent inserts / deletes change the actual row count so it no longer matches the one gathered).

If you need a precise value you'll need to use `SELECT count(*) ...`

Comment: thanks @yangyang how can I loop over all tables in user_tables if I use Select count(*) ... statement ? In this case I will need a stored procedure for that.

Comment: Yes, you'll need to use PL/SQL for that.